# Check/UnCheck Listobx items based of Excel Cell Values

Tags: excel, vba

Could someone help me with this please? I’m trying to select some items (using a checkbox) on a ListBox matching on values from a specified Excel sheet and range. (say from `BR5  up to BR17`, but usually I'll have values in 3/4 cells).

The code below selects all items but I only want to select items that are on range BR5 and onwards

```
Dim x As Integer

For x = 0 To lstDataTracing.ListCount - 1
    If lstDataTracing.Selected(x) = False Then
        lstDataTracing.Selected(x) = True
    End If
Next
```

I’m wondering if I could incorporate the above code into the code below – and this is where I need help please.

```
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
   IsInArray = UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1
End Function

Dim itemExistResults As Boolean

'this populate my listbox - lstDataTracing
myArray = Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f") 

'this part isn’t working – need looping!
If IsInArray(Range("BR5:BR17"), myArray) = True Then 
   itemExistResults = True

   'If I could get the index number for the matched item, 
   'then using the index number I could probably select the items on the ListBox.
   'just for test purpose
    MsgBox "Yes! Item is not in the array" 
Else
    'just for test purpose
    MsgBox "No! Item is not in the array"
End If
```

Comment: Since there are only 12 cells, why are you taking such a long way? Why not loop through the Listbox and the range and then set the `.Selected(x) = True`

Answer (score 0):

Like I mentioned in the comments above, since there are only 12 cells, the most simple way to achieve what you want is to not loop through the Listbox and the range and then set the `.Selected(x) = True`

See this example.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim i As Long

    '~~> Adding test numbers
    For i = 1 To 15
        lstDataTracing.AddItem i
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    '~~> Change this to th relevant worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set rng = ws.Range("BR5:BR17")

    For x = 0 To lstDataTracing.ListCount - 1
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, lstDataTracing.List(x)) Then
            lstDataTracing.Selected(x) = True
        Else
            lstDataTracing.Selected(x) = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**ScreenShot**

[image]

Comment: Dear Siddharth Rout,

Thank you very much – it does what I wanted. You made my day – thank you so much once again.

Best wishes
fmleigh

Comment: Glad to be of help :)